# Batch Inserts and Batch Deletes

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables with same structures in a MS Sql server : T1 and T2, T1 has around 4 Billion rows and T2 is an empty table. Need to insert T1 data in to T2 in batches, After each Batch Insert in to T2 from T1, I have to Delete that data(batch Delete) from T1.
FYI: Tables contains 1 Primary Key and 4 non-clustered indexes

Please suggest me the best options/best query.

Comment: This: http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query to get good performance without using temp table or joining to delete from T1. And it's very simple.

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10000

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 'EXISTS' FROM T1 WHERE COLUMN=VALUE)
BEGIN
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10' -- You can pass it if you want interval between next delete
DELETE FROM T1
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO T2
WHERE COLUMN=VALUE
END

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

You can comment or remove WHERE clause if not required.

Thanks

Comment: `SET ROWCOUNT` should no longer be be used for insert, update, and delete operations per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx. Instead, use `DELETE TOP (10000)...`.